# slicing of data into separate Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
entry_df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), as.Date("2018/01/07"), 
                       "days"),diff = c(1,0,-1 , 0,0 ,1,-1))

entry_df

        date diff
1 2018-01-01    1
2 2018-01-02    0
3 2018-01-03   -1
4 2018-01-04    0
5 2018-01-05    0
6 2018-01-06    1
7 2018-01-07   -1
```

I want to `rbind` the rows that are betwen `1` and `-1` in a `dataframe` and push it on a `list`.

Steps:

1. `2018-01-01` is equal `1` so it will be my first element of my dataframe 
   `2018-01-02` is equal to `0` so I need to rbind it to the first dataframe
   `2018-01-03` is equal to `-1` so I need to rbind it to the first dataframe and that will constitue the first element of the list
2. `2018-01-04` and `2018-01-05` is equal to `0` so i don't do anything ...
3. `2018-01-06` is equal to `1` so i create a dataframe  at it will be the first element of it. `2018-01-07` is equal to `-1` so i will rbind to the dataframe and that will constitute the second element of the list

Expected output is something like this

```
output_list[[1]] <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), 
                               as.Date("2018/01/03"), "days")) 
output_list[[2]] <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018/01/06"),
                               as.Date("2018/01/07"), "days")) 

output_list      

[[1]]
        date
1 2018-01-01
2 2018-01-02
3 2018-01-03

[[2]]
        date
1 2018-01-06
2 2018-01-07
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the number of 1's and -1s are the same, get the index of row with `==` and `which`, then loop over the indexes using `Map` and subset the 1st column of 'entry_df'

```
Map(function(i, j) entry_df[i:j, 1, drop = FALSE], 
           which(entry_df$diff == 1), which(entry_df$diff == -1))
#[[1]]
#        date
#1 2018-01-01
#2 2018-01-02
#3 2018-01-03

#[[2]]
#        date
#6 2018-01-06
#7 2018-01-07
```